# How to use HttpServletRequest in Spring boot 2.x?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to use HttpServletRequest in spring boot 2.x. Here are my example:

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" th:href="${'?'+(#httpServletRequest.getParameter('categoryId')==null?'':('&categoryId='+#httpServletRequest.getParameter('categoryId')))
                                                                                       +(#httpServletRequest.getParameter('page')==null?'':('&page='+#httpServletRequest.getParameter('page')))
                                                                                       +(#httpServletRequest.getParameter('size')==null?'':('&size='+#httpServletRequest.getParameter('size')))
                                                                                       +('&sortByPrice=ASC')
                                                                                       +(#httpServletRequest.getParameter('name')==null?'':('&name='+#httpServletRequest.getParameter('name')))}">Price ASC</a>
```

I use this config but it returns errors about templates. How can I config to use that?

```java
    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory containerFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
                int maxSize = 50000000;
                super.customizeConnector(connector);
                connector.setMaxPostSize(maxSize);
                connector.setMaxSavePostSize(maxSize);
                if (connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {

                    ((AbstractHttp11Protocol <?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(maxSize);
                    logger.info("Set MaxSwallowSize "+ maxSize);
                }
            }
        };

    }

    /**
     * Fix bean cookie
     * @return
     */
    @Component
    public class CustomContainer implements
            WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

        @Override
        public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
            factory.setContextPath("");
            factory.setPort(8080);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could Add **HttpServletRequest** as parameter to your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/") public String home(HttpServletRequest request){
System.out.println("My Attribute :: "+request.getAttribute("YourAttributeName"));
return "home"; }
```

OR

you could access HttpServletRequest via injecting it in your class

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest context;
```